# Why are Java method / constructor parameters not final by default?

Tags: java

`final` fields promote immutability. This is a good thing, IMO. However, I find having to explicitly declare each method parameter and local variable as final, looks noisy and makes LOC wider; I'd just expect it to be the case.

I would have thought that method parameters and local variables being `final` by default would have been the superior decision. Why is this not the case?

Comment: Not really a question for here.

Comment: This is not the place to propose changes or have discussions of the next version(s) of Java. Please direct those questions/discussions to/with Oracle.

Comment: Can you give some examples for "In my experience, good Java developers prefer final parameters."?

Comment: @HoomanYar, if you bothered to read the site rules, then you'd know this is completely off-topic for stackoverflow. This site is for specific programming implementation question. It isn't meant to be a forum for discussing things

Comment: While it might have been better if variables were final by default, I don't consider them adding them really helpful except for fields.  If your method is too complicated to work out if the variables are effectively final your method is too complicated i.e. refactor the method rather than adding final to variables.

Comment: @steffen checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_misc.html#FinalParameters

Comment: Here's an official answer: final-by-default would have been a better choice for both fields and parameters, but that ship sailed in 1995 and there's relatively little value in trying to lock the barn door after the horse has escaped. As @PeterLawrey suggests, even though its good to avoid mutating parameters, its rarely worth the syntactic overhead of making them final (in fact, in Java 8, the compiler infers finality in some situations that previously required explicit finality, such as capture by inner classes.)

Comment: @BrianGoetz I agree, while refactoring constructors and methods to be short and easily understood is a worthy goal in itself, having classes so short they are easily understood is less practical. So while `final` fields is something I prefer and usually the only use of `final` I make, though others won't agree. If having `final` parameters and local variables allows us to have larger, more complex methods, I am not sure this is a win. +1

Comment: Even final variables can be mutated. See effective java, chap 39 IIRC (defensive copying).

Comment: That's really clarified things. Thank you and thanks @steffen. It's such a shame this question wasn't quite suitable for Stack Overflow as I feel it's an interesting one with an answer that will help developers write better code.

Comment: @BrianGoetz now that this has been re-opened, I've created a place-holder answer quoting your comment. If you'd like to formalise your answer, I'll delete the place-holder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an official answer: final-by-default would have been a better choice for both fields and parameters, but that ship sailed in 1995 and there's relatively little value in trying to lock the barn door after the horse has escaped. As @PeterLawrey suggests, even though its good to avoid mutating parameters, its rarely worth the syntactic overhead of making them final (in fact, in Java 8, the compiler infers finality in some situations that previously required explicit finality, such as capture by inner classes.)

Answer (score -3):

Intellij allows you to customize code generation. Under Preferences -> Editor -> Code Style -> Java -> Code Generation.  You can click the button that says `make generated parameters final`.

Comment: The question was directed at parameters, and not local variables.

Comment: Updated. It is the option right next to it. Really didn't require a downvote. Harsh crowd. Trying to answer the part of the question that has an easy answer.

Comment: I can not answer for the down-vote. I did not. I always ping the users before. As you updated it to reflect that I never had to. Now I can guess why the down-votes came though: It does not answer the question. "*as final, however, looks noisy and makes signatures longer*"

Comment: Neither did I downvote your answer, even though I disagreed on your original text. Making method parameters final has no effect on (im)mutability; the object can still be modified. And what's different when declaring method parameters `final` in terms of concurrency?